# Protected 3.7v battery as replacement for 3.8

Tags: batteries, lipo

I have a set of bodycams that need replacement batteries, and i cannot find anything suitable short of 400 quid to send them back to manufacturer. At that price i might as well spend the extra 100 and buy new ones.

The originals are 3.8v, 2000mah x 2 bagged cells at 45mm square.

Can i replace them with protected 3.7v cells and trust the protection board to prevent overcharge?

I would assume the cameras would only read 90% battery when full and try to continue to trickle, but will the charge profile ruin the replacement cells, or worse release the magic smoke?

Comment: This is currently unanswerable. Without being specific about the protected cells and their protection circuitry there's no way to know if they have something to prevent overcharging. Is the chemistry the same for the originals and replacements?

Comment: IF these are Lithium Ion cells then the 3.8V and 3.7V ratings are nominal mean voltages. A LiIon cell is at about 4.2V fully charged dropping to about 3V when fully discharged. |. Charge the existing battery (if still working). If Vbat unloaded is about 4.2V you (almost certainly) have a LiIon cell and the 3.7V cell will (almost certainly) work perfectly well. Having the same mAh rating is desirable. A higher mAh new cell will take longer to charge BUT will OVERcharge somewhat due to the way LiIon charging works. Photos of old and new cells and specs such as are known will help .

Comment: Sorry to say the old cells are swollen beyond the point i would trust them to charge and not do something nasty. They are marked 3.8v 1970mah, and the rest of the text is ruined by the double sided tape holding the two together. I havent purchased new cells, as i cant find anything the right physical size and nominal voltage to fit. I was under the impression that 3.8v cells charged to 4.35 volts not 4.2, hence my concern about the mismatching of replacements and possible release of magic smoke and or magic fire!

Answer (score 1):

NB: This is a "best attempt" answer.
It is very probably correct but is offered on a no responsibility YMMV basis.
In your position I'd take my advice :-).

IF these are Lithium Ion cells then the 3.8V and 3.7V ratings are nominal mean voltages. A LiIon cell is at about 4.2V fully charged dropping to about 3V when fully discharged.

Charge the existing battery (if still working).
If Vbat unloaded is about 4.2V you (almost certainly) have a LiIon cell and the 3.7V cell will (almost certainly) work perfectly well.

Having the same mAh rating is desirable.
A higher mAh new cell will take longer to charge BUT will OVERcharge somewhat due to the way LiIon charging works.

Photos of old and new cells and specs such as are known will help .